# Is $G = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}a & -b \\ b & a\end{bmatrix} : a,b \in \Bbb R \right\}$ under matrix multiplication a monoid, semigroup, or neither?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, monoid

Determine whether $( G , \ast )$ is a monoid or semigroup or neither, where $$G = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}a & -b \\ b & a\end{bmatrix}  : a,b  \in  \Bbb R \right\}$$ and $\ast$ is product of matrices

i tired solve it :

by ${ x*x^{-1} }$ = I = ${ \begin{bmatrix}{1} && {0} \\ {0} && {1}\end{bmatrix} }$  but i get finally i =${ \begin{bmatrix}{aa} && {0} \\ {0} && 
{bb}\end{bmatrix} }$ is my steps is Right ? is these Group according  to 
 ${ x*x^{-1} = e }$  ?

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a monoid (and hence also a semigroup).

First, we have to show that $I_2 \in G$. Indeed, setting $a=1$ and $b=0$ gives the identity matrix.

Second, we have to show that $G$ is closed under multiplication. Suppose that $\begin{bmatrix} a&-b \\ b&a \end{bmatrix} \in G$ and $\begin{bmatrix} c&-d \\ d&c \end{bmatrix} \in G$. Then, we have

$$\begin{bmatrix} a&-b \\ b&a \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} c&-d \\ d&c \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} ac-bd&-(ad+bc) \\ ad+bc&ac-bd \end{bmatrix} \in G$$, so $G$ is closed under multiplication.

Finally, multiplication of matrices is associative in general, so it is in particular associative for matrices in $G$.

Alternatively, we could instead use the fact that $G$ is isomorphic to the monoid of complex numbers under multiplication via the map $\begin{bmatrix} a&-b \\ b&a \end{bmatrix} \mapsto a+bi$, and the fact that multiplication of complex numbers is associative.

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be a semigroup without being a monoid since $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\in G$$ by setting $a=1$ and $b=0$; that is, there is an identity element in $G$ with respect to $\ast$.

What's left is to check whether $(G, \ast)$ is closed and associative.

Comment: This is not the main point. The associativity of the product of matrices is known. The argument is to verify that this set is closed under product, a different issue (still very easy).

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, @J.-E.Pin; I've edited the answer accordingly.